# got 417 response in twitter

Tags: php, curl, twitter

In my server I have enabled the cURL module, I am even using some contact grabber and PayPal, and so many applications with cURL.

But, I don't know why this Twitter showing the HTTP response code as `417`.

This is my snippet:

```
$host = "http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=".urlencode(stripslashes(urldecode($message)));
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
// Look at the returned header
$resultArray = curl_getinfo($ch);

curl_close($ch);
if($resultArray['http_code'] == "200"){
    $twitter_status='Your message has been sended! <a href="http://twitter.com/'.$username.'">See your profile</a>';
} else {
     $twitter_status="Error posting to Twitter. Retry";
}

return $twitter_status;
```

(This snippet works fine in my local development environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also including this line in your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```